# How do I do the car-door-sukkah trick?

Tags: travel, sukkot, sukkah, vehicles-transportation, how-to

I know in theory, people on the road don't need to eat in a sukkah; at the same time, you're not supposed to go put yourself in that situation on purpose.  ("Let's go take a chol hamoed trip -- oops we're travelling, no need for sukkah.")

I heard in yeshiva that if you keep schach in your car (let's assume a mat), you could open the front and rear doors on one side (leaving the other doors closed), put schach up between the open doors, and sit (low to the ground, I assume) in that small space.  (See awful ASCII art, if that helps.)  The doors are two walls (assuming they're *lavud* to the ground and tall enough), the third wall is the other side of the car (*dofen akuma*.)

Has anyone ever heard of this or tried it?  Which dimensions on a car are needed?  (Where can I see those dimensions listed?)  Any other thoughts?

```
   _____
__|    |
       |
 x     |
__     |
  |____|
```

Comment: If you're particular about using sechach-eligible materials for direct sechach support, you'll also need some (e.g.) plain wooden beams to put across the doors and hold up the sechach.

Comment: Another issue is place. It is not clear that a suucah would be kosher if in a place where one would be too fearful to sleep in it.

Comment: In the same vain as above today I highly suggest a Pop up Sukkah.

Comment: I recall that R' Moshe held that the p'tur applies to someone travelling on business.  Traveling for pleasure would be chayav (not just don't put yourself in that situation).  I don't remember if it's in print, but I'll look.

Comment: My recollection as I've heard the Igros Moshe was that once you're a "traveller", you're technically exempt; however, no good Jew should put himself in an oops-no-mitzva situation just for a pleasure trip.

Comment: Iggros Moshe O.C. III 93  http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=400

Comment: YDK, thanks for sharing.  You appear to be correct, but I'd like to read/think it over some more.

Answer (score 8):

In theory it should work with the following qualifications:

1- Your car roof width from the far inner door to the schach area is 4 amos or less (for dofen akuma)

2- Your car doors are less than 3 tefachim off the ground (for mechitza- gediim bok'im)

Like you mentioned, you need the second door for the third wall, just resting it on the roof won't help.

Comment: what's the minimum length/width/height of this sukkah?

Comment: The 4 amos could be tricky.  If we take the minimal shiur of 18 inches=1cubit, that gives us 6 ft; I think only smaller cars have a width less than six feet.  (I'm assuming car width = roof width.)  If we go up to 22.5 inches/cubit, then you're fine with any car or minivan I can think of -- width less than 7.5 ft.

Comment: Regular sukkah rules apply:  The eating area need to be 7x7 tefachim, so the walls, measured from the inside, are 7t.  The height is 10t, but you can use the <3t space between the bottom of the door and the ground.  Your food needs to be inside the sukkah area (gezeira shema yimshach).

Comment: Minivans will be a problem anyway, since they don't have a rear door that opens 7t.  They probably also have more than 3t between the ground and the front door.  This trick seems to be limited to sedans.

Comment: Oh right forgot about the sliding door.  (Well on most minivans.)  If the ground-to-door height (what's that called?) is too great, you could bring a couple of bricks or something to put on the ground.

Comment: But we're getting complicated enough ("yeshivish"!) as is.  Yeah, maybe stick with sedans.

Comment: Just stay home, learn in your Sukkah and be "with Hashem"! (Oh to be a Yeshiva Bachur again and not need to deal with the reality of providing other types of simcha for family members that requires leaving the Sukkah!)

Comment: @Yahu But, then again, we're looking for answers connected to the real world and not theoretical, laboratory-condition Judaism.

Comment: @YDK You could add [this article](http://www.jewishworldreview.com/1000/sukkah.car.html) (which cites R' Moshe Heinemann's heter) or [this Halachipedia article](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Building_the_Sukkah#Materials_for_walls_of_Sukkah) (citing the same R' Heinemann) to strengthen your answer.