# Can I use a car's sunroof as a sukkah?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, vehicles-transportation

Can I use a car's sunroof as a sukkah? Taking my Subaru Forrester as an example to get some approximate numbers: it has a sunroof of approximately 30 inches by 30 inches.  This exceeds all opinions of what constitutes 7 x 7 tephachim.

The sunroof is a few inches from the windshield and from the doors.  Am I right that I am covered by Dofen Akumah?

Is the slant in the windshield a problem or prevent it from being a wall? I don't think this is a problem but I am just checking.

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/how-do-i-do-the-car-door-sukkah-trick

Comment: Sounds plausible, if you can get yourself positioned under the opening - rosho ve-rubo

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, you have 3 Kosher walls, which is sufficient - and maybe 4 - depending on how large your windshield is; up to 4 Amos you are allowed a דופן עקומה. (You may want to check the statusof the back window also).

You also have the required 7x7 tefachim.

The only missing info is the height - you need 10 Tefachim of **useable** height on an area of 7x7. Since your car seats are solidly attached to the floor (I hope), I don't think you could start measuring from underneath the seats.

See the Aruch Hashulchan 633:10 who says:

> ולכן סוכה אין החלל שלה גבוה עשרה טפחים – פסולה. ואפילו היא גבוה עשרה טפחים, והסכך הוא למעלה מעשרה, אלא שהוצין יורדין לתוך עשרה – גם כן פסולה, ואפילו הם חמתה מרובה מצילתה, דאין הפסול מטעם הסכך אלא משום **דלא נשאר עשרה טפחים אויר לתשמיש, ואינה דירת אדם.**