# Can you build a succah on Sukkot?

Tags: halacha, time, sukkot, sukkah

After reading [How do I do the car-door-sukkah trick?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/how-do-i-do-the-car-door-sukkah-trick), i wondered: isn't this building it on Sukkot?

So, is it permissible to build a succah on Sukkot?

I originally thought no, because i know that the succah is muktzah for all of chag. Also, per [When can you build the sukkah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/when-can-you-build-the-sukkah), it seems that it should be done within 30 days of the chag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a Machloket in the Talmud (Sukkah [27b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=27b&format=pdf), see OC 637) and the Halacha follows the Sages that one can start building a Sukkah on Chol HaMoed. Even R Eliezer who argued there agreed that if one's Sukkah fell down on Chol HaMoed that one can rebuild it.

Comment: I wonder if R' Eliezer would also agree that in a case in which one was traveling and therefore exempt from sukka, one could build one on Chol Hamoed based on that "excuse."

Comment: @IsaacMoses Unlikely, given his reasoning there.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, people go on Hol Hamo'ed trips and pack a "pop up" succah with them. Or, they build a small succah where they are.

Years ago, I went on a singles' vacation, and someone built a "Superman booth" - a small succah that fit 1 person. Apparently, there is no problem building a succah on Hol Hamo'ed.

Comment: I too had the experience of helping build a "pop up" Succah during Chol Hamoed for a Succos party at a park hosted by an orthodox kollel.  After the party was over I also had to help disassemble it. Therefore disassembling must be kosher too else they wouldn't have had me do it.

Comment: a great idea to pop up a succah but one is forbidden to take it down till after simchas tora as it then becomes mukza see S.A O.C 638,1