# Can Schach that fell be restored on Shabbat/Chag?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, schach

If the Schach or a portion of it fell/flew off during Shabbat/Chag, can it be placed back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you build a succah on Sukkot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46186/can-you-build-a-succah-on-sukkot)

Comment: That answers about chol hamoed but not Yom Yov or Shabbat. It would be muktzah on Yom Tov or Shabbat and asur to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Schach* is *muktzeh* therefore cannot be fixed by a Jew during *chag* or Shabbat, but can be fixed during *hol hamoed*.**

See for instance [this digest of Sukkot laws](https://crownheights.info/assets/2017/09/Sukkos.pdf)

> If Schach blows out of place on Yom Tov, one may not fix it, since the
>   Schach is Muktzeh. However, if the Sukkah is no longer Kosher (or its
>   status is questionable), one should consult with a Rov as to whether a
>   [non-Jew] can fix it.

or what dinonline writes [here](http://dinonline.org/2011/11/21/fixing-the-sechach/)

> There is no problem in fixing the sechach during Sukkos. This cannot
>   be done on Yom Tov, but only on Chol Hamoed. On Yom Tov, it can be
>   done by hinting to a non-Jew.